# How to accept 3 arguments as int

Tags: c

For example:

```
console> please enter 3 digits: 1 2 3
```

I only know how to accept 1 digit using `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d", &space);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read in multiple numbers with scanf

```
int a, b, c;
scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that the spaces in the format string (i.e.: "%d %d %d") have no real effect on how the user will separate the 3 ints.  scanf will "eat" any white space (space, tab, etc.) separating the ints.

Comment: Very true, but I like to put the white space in for readability.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);
```

That will work fine if you know you want just the three. If you want a variable number, you'll need to do it in a loop, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int i, ch, rc, val, count;

    // Loop until we get a valid number.

    rc = 0;
    while (rc != 1) {
        printf ("Enter count: "); fflush (stdout);
        rc = scanf(" %d", &count);

        // Suck up all characters to line end if bad conversion.

        if (rc != 1) while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n');
    }

    // Do once for each number.

    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        rc = 0;
        while (rc != 1) {
            printf ("\nEnter #% 2d: ", i); fflush (stdout);
            rc = scanf(" %d", &val);
            if (rc != 1) while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n');
        }
        printf ("You entered %d\n", val);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Running this gives you:

```
Enter count: 5

Enter # 1: 10
You entered 10

Enter # 2: 20
You entered 20

Enter # 3: 30
You entered 30

Enter # 4: 40
You entered 40

Enter # 5: 99
You entered 99
```